# $|A|<|C|$ and $|B|=|D|$ then $|A\cup B|<2|C\cup D|$ but $|A\cup B|\leq|C\cup D|$ need not always be true.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ and $D$ be finite sets such that $|A|<|C|$ and $|B|=|D|$, where $|A|$ stands for the number of elements in the set $A$. Then $|A\cup B|<2|C\cup D|$ but $|A\cup B|\leq|C\cup D|$ need not always be true.

How is that conclusion derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, using the assumptions $|A|<|C|\tag1$ and $$|B|=|D|\tag2$$ we have that  $$|A\cup B| \le |A|+|B| <^{(1)}|C|+|B|=^{(2)}|C|+|D|\le|C\cup D|+|C\cup D|=2|C\cup D|$$

For the second part: Assume that $A=\{1,2\}, C=\{3,4,5\}$ and $B=C=D$. Then $|A|<|C|$ and $|B|=|D|$ and $$|A\cup B|=5>3=|C\cup D|$$

Comment: @Sush Haha, you are welcome mate

Comment: Will you please answer [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14473192#14473192) on chat, please?

Answer (score 1):

Since $|C|+|D|\ge 2|C\cap D|$, then

$|A\cup B|\le|A|+|B|<|C|+|D|\le 2(|C|+|D|-|C\cap D|)=2|C\cup D|$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{3,4\}$, $C=D=\{1,2\}$. Then $|A\cup B|=3>2=|C\cup D|$.

On the other hand $|A\cup B|=|A\cup (B-A)|=|A|+|B-A|<|C|+|B-A|\le |C|+|D|$. Now, $|C|+|D|\le 2|C\cup D|$, since $|C\cup D|\ge |C|,|D|$.